# Why is my theme's block preprocess function not reordering elements?

Tags: search, theming

I'm trying to do something that seems fairly basic, but I'm having loads of trouble.

The drupal search_form block outputs an input field and a submit button, in that order.  I'd like to swap the order of those fields.  I'm using `theme_preprocess_search_block_form` to attempt to reverse the order.  This is my current function:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_search_block_form(&$data)
{

    $data['form']['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = 'Search ...';
    $data['form'] = array_reverse($data['form']);
    foreach(element_children($data['form']) as $k) {
        if(!empty($data['form'][$k]['#weight'])) {
            $data['form'][$k]['#weight'] *= -1;
        }
    }

    $data['form']['#sorted'] = FALSE;
}
```

This function *does* get called, since a `var_dump` will output to the browser, however, the changes don't make it to the front end. So, what is unchanging my changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Drupal can be so infuriating when you are new to it.

The rendering of the search_form_block was happening in a template function file:

`bootstrap-search-form-wrapper.func.php.`

containing:

`function bootstrap_bootstrap_search_form_wrapper($variables)`

The function customizes the rendering of the search form by calling out elements specifically - thus ignoring `'#weight'`; the wrapper function is part of the bootstrap theme.

The solution is to overwrite the bootstrap theme function with a similar function in our child theme: `function mytheme_bootstrap_search_form_wrapper($variables)`

o.O

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: once you can, you should mark your own answer as the accepted answer so this doesn't keep showing up as unanswered

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, SE wouldn't let me until 2 days after asking for some reason.